# Reinforcing concrete parapet?

Tags: repair, walls, concrete, floor, foundation

One small section of our roof's parapet looks like this. We will be installing one 3/8" x 3" havy-duty concrete screw anchor in that area.

The ideal solution is to remove and replace with new concrete. But we can't do that at the moment, so we need to find another way.

That piece of concrete is not loose, but I think it's not strong enough to withstand drilling and screwing in one of these huge screws.

So my question is: is there a product that I can use/pour that will reinforce that piece of concrete to withstand drilling and installing a 3/8" x 3" anchor?

Thanks.
[image]

Comment: There's also the concern of whatever the screw is holding applying force to this weakened area, and causing it to come loose as a result.

Comment: Just remove the bad part for now, So it does not kill someone and fix later.

Answer (score 1):

A lot depends upon the nature of the cracked part of the concrete. If that is just a thin piece cracked from the surface then that piece will almost certainly crack when trying to drill into it. But that said if the underlying bulk of the concrete is intact for a good thickness of four to five inches then it would likely be able to hold the anchor that you described.

On the other hand if the crack shown in your picture has cleaved the whole corner of that part of the concrete then you will not have a good result trying to drill into that area.

There is really no good solution to how to reinforce that area without outright replacement. Since this is part of a roof there are limited options.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than drill into the area that’s broken, I’d encase the area.

In order to secure an encasement to the wall, I’d anchor it back where the wall is solid. The encasement can be made out of a wood or steel frame covered with something to make it waterproof. (I’d make the encasement waterproof so it’s not affected by freeze/thaw effect too. )